# Insert MongoDB ISODate PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, isodate, mongodate

I am using the following versions:

```
PHP                -> 5.6.11  
MongoDB            -> 3.2  
MongoDB PHP Driver -> 1.1
```

When I was looking to install a MongoDB PHP driver [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) I noticed that the driver named "Mongo" had been deprecated and proceeded to follow the provided link to install the new extension "MongoDB". This will be referred to as ***php_mongodb***. Since I am using a Windows System I had to copy the file `php_mongodb.dll` to my `../php/ext` and added the line `extension=php_mongodb.dll` to my PHP.ini

Using the now deprecated driver I used to be able to insert a MongoDate() as shown below.

```
<?php
    $connection = new MongoClient();
    $database = $connection->selectDB('test');
    $coll = new MongoCollection($database, 'users');

    $coll->insert(
        (object)array(
            "createdAt" => new MongoDate()
        )
    );
?>
```

The Problem is that with the new php_mongodb this MongoDate() does not seem to be available I receive the error: `Fatal error: Class 'MongoDate' not found`

- What is the equivalent to this using new ***php_mongodb*** driver?
- Should I consider downgrading my version of MongoDB to 3.0 so that I can use the now legacy Mongo Driver?
- Is there a PHP native way to make a date that is of type ISODate?

Should I consider downgrading my version of MongoDB to 3.0 so that I can use the now legacy Mongo Driver?

This is what I've tried to no avail, the following will add a value of type `Timestamp` to a Document, however it seems that because it is not of type `ISODate` that I am unable to enforce [TTL](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/) with this `createdAt` field:

```
<?php
    require '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $date = new MongoDB\BSON\Timestamp(1, date('U'));

    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
    $collection = new MongoDB\Collection($manager, "test.users");
    
    $ex = [
        "createdAt" => $date
    ];
    
    $result = $collection->insertOne( $ex );
?>
```

Another thing I have tried is the below date, however without the MongoDate() functionality I do not know how to insert this as the type `ISODate` for MongoDB:
`date(DATE_ISO8601, date('U'));`

Comment: Try var_dump(extension_loaded('mongodb')); and see what is the output.

Comment: @Nikhil this returns True

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if you still need this, but i have been struggling a lot with this. Finally i have been able to figure it out.

```
$orig_date = new DateTime('2016-01-22  14:00:00');
# or you can use any other way to construct with (int timestamp)
$mongo_date = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($orig_date->getTimestamp());
$filter = [
          ....
           ....
            ['timestamp' => ['$gte' =>  $mongo_date]],
           ....
          ....
]
# create command (for example aggregation)
$cmd = new MongoDB\Driver\Command( $filter );
# execute command
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('my_mongo_db_name', $cmd);
```

This code works for me.

Comment: It looks UTCDateTime actually expects milleseconds (`$orig_date->getTimestamp()` passes seconds). So you can either do `$orig_date->getTimestamp() * 1000` or even easier is to pass the DateTime object like so: `new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($orig_date);`. The documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php